# WebApi Authorization Filter

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, autofac, asp.net-web-api2

I have a web api authorization filter that is applied to the base controller of a web api controller. Authorization type is Basic. The authorization filter is using the IAutofacAuthenticationFilter and is using some autofac injected services to perform authorization and authentication.

Everything works as expected on GET requests. 
The authorization header is read and confirmed and in case the request does not have the proper authorization information in the authorization header the request is responded to using.

```
public void OnChallenge(HttpAuthenticationChallengeContext context) {
    var host = context.Request.RequestUri.DnsSafeHost;
    context.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized, "Unauthenticated request");
    context.Request.Headers.Add("WWW-Authenticate", string.Format("Basic realm=\"{0}\"", host));
}
```

However, when a POST request is made, everything is called the same way and the above method gets called as expected, but the request keeps on processing by going to the actual controller action.

OnAuthorization is not modified or overloaded. Instead,

OnAuthenticate looks like this:

```
public void OnAuthenticate(HttpAuthenticationContext context)
    {


        var identity = ParseAuthorizationHeader(context.ActionContext); // identity is a custom object representing the information in the auth header
        if (identity == null) {
            HandleUnauthorizedRequest(context.ActionContext);
            return;
        }


        if (!OnAuthorizeUser(identity.Name, identity.Key, context.ActionContext)) {
            HandleUnauthorizedRequest(context.ActionContext);
            return;
        }
    }
```

Here is a custom method to set the principal and authenticate the user:

```
protected virtual bool OnAuthorizeUser(KeyContainer name, string key, HttpActionContext actionContext) {

        // get principal code ...

        Thread.CurrentPrincipal = principal;
        actionContext.RequestContext.Principal = principal;
        if (HttpContext.Current != null)
            HttpContext.Current.User = principal;

        return true;
    }
```

The authorization filter is registered with the container with the following:

```
builder.Register(c =>
           new AuthorizeActionFilterAttribute(
               c.Resolve<IService>())
           .AsWebApiAuthenticationFilterFor<BaseApiController>()
           .InstancePerRequest();
```

What's happening in a POST request that is different than the GET one and how can this be fixed?

Comment: What are you doing in the OnAuthenticate method?

Comment: @PeterLillevold I updated the question with more information. The interesting thing is that if i don't use the IAutofacAuthenticationFilter interface from Autofac and resolve the services i need using `var dependecyScope = actionContext.Request.GetDependencyScope();var lifetimeScope = dependecyScope.GetRequestLifetimeScope();_service = lifetimeScope.Resolve<IService>()` and decorate the Base api controller with the filter, the problem goes away.

Answer (score 2):

I am guessing that the problem is with the `InstancePerRequest` registration of the filter. We have a [fairly extensive FAQ on per-request scope usage](http://autofac.readthedocs.org/en/latest/faq/per-request-scope.html) and part of that notes that [you can't have per-request dependencies in filters](http://autofac.readthedocs.org/en/latest/faq/per-request-scope.html#no-per-request-filter-dependencies-in-web-api) because WebAPI caches filter instances for controllers once they're created - the only way to successfully make that work (as you've discovered) is to use service location from within the filter itself. Unfortunately there's nothing we can do from an Autofac side; it's all built-in and not-overridable in WebAPI to behave that way.

Hopefully they'll change that in ASP.NET vNext.

Comment: Wouldn't caching affect both GET and POST requests? The problem only occurs on post requests though. I will check out the FAQ.